# Quadratic form of nonlinear differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms, nonlinear-system

I've got nonlinear differential equations like this:
\begin{equation}
\vec{y}={\begin{pmatrix} S\\E\\I\\R \end{pmatrix}},\vec{f}(x,\vec{y})=\frac{\partial \vec{y}}{\partial t}={\begin{pmatrix}
  -10^{-6}SI\\10^{-6}SI-0.4E\\0.4E-0.5I\\0.5I
\end{pmatrix}}
\end{equation}
In class my TA tell us we can rewrite it in quadratic from:
$Y_{n \times 1}^{\prime}=f\left(x, Y_{n \times 1}\right)=B_{n \times 1} Y_{n \times 1}^{T} A_{n \times n} Y_{n \times 1}+C_{n \times n} Y_{n \times 1}$,so we can get it derivative for further calculating,But I don't have an idea how to get Matrix B and A,is there any limit or I can just write a special form which I guess out?

Comment: The only quadratic terms involve the ${\tt1}^{st}$ and ${\tt3}^{rd}$ components of $\vec y$, so the $A$ matrix is sparse. The rest of the problem is linear. Everything can be expressed in terms of the standard basis vectors $\{\vec e_k\}$
$$\eqalign{
A &= \vec e_1\vec e_3^T \\
B &= 10^{-6}(\vec e_2-\vec e_1) \\
C &= \Big[\matrix{\vec 0&0.4(\vec e_3-\vec e_2)&0.5(\vec e_4-\vec e_3)&\vec 0}\Big] \\
}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}
S\\
E\\
I\\
R
\end{bmatrix} \, = \, \begin{bmatrix}
-10^{-6}\\
\,\,\,\,\,10^{-6}\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix} \Big[
S \,\, E \,\, I \,\,  R \Big]\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
S\\
E\\
I\\
R
\end{bmatrix} \,+\, \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -0.4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \,\,\,\,0.4 & -0.5 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \,\,\,\,0.5 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
S\\
E\\
I\\
R
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}